# ASP.Net Session data lost between pages

Tags: c#, .net, iis, session, session-variables

I came across a weird behavior today w/ my web application. When I navigate from a page to another, I lose one particular session variable data.

I'm able to launch the app in firefox and able to see that the session data is not lost.

I use `Response.Redirect(page2, false)` to redirect to another page.

Below code was used to track session variables

```
System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\test.txt", true);
for (int i = 0; i < Session.Count; i++)
{
 sw.WriteLine(Session.Keys[i] + " " + Session.Contents[i]);
}
sw.Close();
```

Can anyone help me in this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Comment: What exactly is happening and how are you able to view the server side session variables on the client side (firefox)?  What exactly are you using, and have you checked the web.config to ensure that the session timeout is not 0?

Answer (score 3):

I was having exactly the same problem and in my case I found the cause of this behavior. It turned out to be that when I was invoking the Response.Redirect() method I was using the full url instead of just the page name. So when I was in localhost/myapp/page1.aspx I redirected to MYMACHINENAME/myapp/page2.aspx and that's why the sessions were different for each page. I corrected this in my code using only "page2.aspx" and then the final url on any browser (IE, firefox) was localhost/myapp/page2.aspx.Don't know if you're playing with the urls the way I was doing it but maybe this answer can give you a clue. Thanks and good coding

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing in a web farm / web garden environment?

Comment: No am not developing in web farm/ web garden environment

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [state server mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx). Depending on how your application pool is configured and your deployments the default in-process mode can be unpredictable.

Comment: I can try state server mode but since this code (with InProc mode) was for a long time and also present in 3 other environments, I can't change it. But, I have no idea why this issue shows up now

Comment: What about cookies then? Watch it with fiddler and/or watch the session id for changes.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was as follows :-

Problem: When we have moved the ASP.NET application to an another server (Windows Server 2008 R2) with IIS 7.5, the application cannot move session values between the pages. e.g. the session value was set in first page but it could not move to next page. In next page, value for same session variable was coming NULL.

Session values was moving to next page in case of Google Chrome and Firefox but not in Internet Explorer.

Resolution: We have created URL name with "_" (underscore) e.g. http://MySite_test.com. After removing "_", it works as required e.g. http://MySitetest.com

Other Possible Solution:

1. Use Response.Redirect with having second parameter as "false" to avoid execution of page and thus to avoid lose session token. You have to use URL as follows. Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx",false)
2. If the application pool of the site is configured as a web farm or a web garden (by setting the maximum number of worker processes to more than one), and if you're not using the session service or SQL sessions, incoming requests will unpredictably go to one of the worker processes, and if it's not the one the session was created on, it's lost. The solutions to this problem is either not to use a web garden if you don't need the performance boost, or use one of the out of process session providers.