# Does anyone else have issues losing session variables in Firefox but not in Chrome or IE?

Tags: c#, firefox, asp.net-mvc-5

We are experiencing some issues with returning variables stored in session, which in turn is causing our controller authorization code to redirect some users back to the login page. The users only seem to be having this issue with the Firefox browser and the application works normally for them when using Chrome or Edge. It's almost as if their session is being dropped while navigating through the site (mostly immediately after login while being redirected to the home page, however sometimes the user can get through few links before being kicked out).The issue also only happens after if is running in our test or production sites, reproducing the issue locally troublesome.  I was wondering if anyone else has experience this type of issue before and if they were able to find a work around or resolve it. Our sessionstate is set to InProc.

Based on other threads I have read on here I have tried the following so far:
Ensured that Session_Start is in Global.asax, Tried setting a "dummy" session variable in the Session_Start method "Session["Init"] = 1", added this to our web.config file  under the  section 

, as well as some other solutions I have found that turned out not to resolve our issue.

This is the section of code in question.

```
public class AuthorizeSessionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpSessionStateBase session = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
            Controller controller = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

            if (controller != null && session != null && session["CurrentRole"] == null)
            {
                controller.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login");
            }

            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

I just can't see any obvious reason as to why this would only happen in Firefox but work correctly in Chrome or IE. Any input on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503378/asp-net-session-data-lost-between-pages

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately none of the suggestions in that link solved my issue.

Comment: @RicardoCedeno Please see the bug report here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1617361

Comment: @RicardoCedeno did you ever find a solution to this?